# Residual Plot vs Fitted, linearity and Heteroskedasticity

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, linear-model

I am working on a linear Regression Model right now,
it has the following format:

```
leisure = ß0 + ß1*age + ß2*log(rain +1) + ß3*log(temperature + 1) + ß4*km + ß5*time
```

So basically I want to know if rain and temperature has an impact on the number of leisure activities a person spends (leisure is a fractional number)
I had to add a small constant when taking the log, because rain and temperature can take zero values.
I plotted a Residual vs. Fitted Plot and I am wondering if I interpret it the right way.
The red line is nearly horizontal which should indicate that there is a linear relationship between my independent variables and my dependent variable leisure.
However the plot also shows me that I have a massiv problem with Heteroskedasticity.
I thought about using FGLS to deal with my Heteroskedasticity.
I am grateful for any suggestions and input.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: You say the response is a fractional number, but you also say that it is a count. How exactly is it measured /  computed ?The residual plot shows that the response is perhaps ordinal, or discreet, so a linear model isn't appropriate here.

Comment: yes it is a count variable, however it became fractional in my data frame because it is weighted.

Comment: What is weighted? How are you getting that value into your data frame?

Comment: the variable leisure is weighted at the path level, so basically it got adjusted which made it to a fractional variable. Do you have an idea which type of a regression I could use if I have a fractional count variable ? Thank you

Comment: A "fractional count variable" does not make sense to me. The counting numbers are the positive (or non-negative) integers, not $5.3$.

Comment: Also, what is your reason for log-transforming the predictors ?

Comment: I ran a partial residual plot and it showed some need for transformation

Comment: A plot of residuals cannot show anything about the predictors. Also, could you please say what a fractional count is?

Comment: Okay I read that crPlot from the car package are commonly used to detect possible non-linearity between a specific predictor and the response.

Comment: That would be more like if there is a need for a quadratic term (residuals look like a parabola), not a log transform to resolve skewness.

Comment: I am aware that there is not such a thing as a fractional count number, however in my data frame I do have one, it is used to to compensate for skew of the sample compared to the population

Comment: I do not care if "fractional count number" is just a term to describe something that you are not sure what it is, but it will be important for you to say how you wind up with those numbers.

Comment: okay..I wil deal with it., Thank you anyway. Just one more question, regarding the transformation of my two independent variables, I tried to do a quadratic transformation and my residual vs. Fitted Plot, doesn't look better, in fact the red line got "worse" (no longer as horizontal), which indicates to me that a log transformation is needed.

Comment: That would be a reasonable separate question. Quickly here, just because a quadratic does not fit does not mean that log is the way to go. Consider if the right transformation is sine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your reponse variable is a count, then you need to fit a model for count data, such as a poisson or negative binomial, for example:

```
glm(leisure ~ age + rain + temperature + km + time, family = poisson(link = "log", data = mydata)
```

It appears from the residual plot that you have just used `lm`

Since your interest is on the impact of rain and temperature, you might want to consider an interaction between these, if you think the effect of one is different depending on the level of the other. Also, a nonlinear association may be indicated - for example when the weather is extremely cold or extremely hot, some exercise may be reduced. So perhaps a quadratic term, or splines would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I can't take the poisson or negative binomial because I have fractional numbers (so leisure can take any number such as 3.55 or 2.4)

Comment: Don't use fractions - a fractional count does not make sense

Comment: @danielarodriguez It is very unclear how and why you are weighting your counts. But I suspect you should leave the counts unchanged and put the weights into the model instead.

Comment: Thank you, that in fact is a very good idea. The weights were needed to overcome the skewness in my sample in relation to the population, if that makes sense.